# Cakephp 3.3.0-RC1: Headers already sent

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

After updating to cakephp 3.3.0-RC1, in my logs I have something like this:

```
2016-08-09 14:20:45 Warning: Headers already sent in /home/mirko/Server/mirkopagliai/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Filter/AssetFilter.php:149
```

How do I figure out where the headers are sent again?

Comment: please add some of code which you written in requested action method

Comment: @HareshVidja, I don't know what is the action, it is precisely what I'm asking ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I figure out where the headers are sent again?

For example by using a proper debugging environment, where you can set a breakpoint for the `Log::warning()` call in `Response::sendHeaders()`, and inspect the control flow.

Alternatively by (temporarily) hacking the core, and adding a stacktrace to the log, which you can inspect to figure what's going on. In `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Netork/Response.php` modify the `Log::warning()` call in the `sendHeaders()` method to something like

```
$trace = \Cake\Error\Debugger::trace();
Log::warning("Headers already sent in {$file}:{$line}\nStack Trace:\n{$trace}\n");
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.3.0-RC1/src/Network/Response.php#L453**

Comment: Thanks @ndm, you're always very helpful and clear.
Do you think it would be useful to propose definitely your hacking? That warning in that way is useless.

Comment: Not sure, there are certainly pros as well as cons... however you can always open a ticket over at GitHub and see what others think about it. @MirkoPagliai